The app crashes when I delete a note from Realm
Can't solve the problem with deleting a note in my app. There is a problem when I delete a note, the application sometimes crashes (for example, it happens if I added 3 notes and deleted the first one, then it crashes), but it happens that I add several notes and I can delete them without any problems. I don't know what the problem might be, so I'm asking for your help.
Viewmodel
func deleteNote(atIndex index: Int) {

  guard notes.indices.contains(index) else { return }

  do {
    let realm = try Realm()
    try realm.write {
      // Improved approach: Get object reference from results to avoid invalidation
      if let objectToDelete = realm.objects(Note.self).filter("id == %@", notes[index].id).first {
        realm.delete(objectToDelete)
        // Remove from in-memory list after successful deletion in Realm
        notes.remove(at: index)
      } else {
        print("Note not found in Realm for deletion (index: \(index))")
      }
    }
  } catch {
    print("Error deleting note: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
}

Note is deleted via swipe .onDelete. Code:
 .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
  guard let index = indexSet.first else { return }
  viewModel.deleteNote(atIndex: index)
})

**Error:** Exception    NSException *   "Object has been deleted or invalidated."   0x0000600000ca6ac0
name    __NSCFConstantString *  "RLMException"  0x0000000105ad44e0
reason  __NSCFString *  "Object has been deleted or invalidated."   0x00006000017a3280
userInfo    __NSDictionaryM *   2 key/value pairs   0x000060000054fd00
reserved    __NSDictionaryM *   2 key/value pairs   0x000060000054fcc0

My guess is that the error occurs in this line realm.delete(objectToDelete)
func getNotes() {
    let realm = try! Realm() // Get a Realm instance
    
    notes = Array(realm.objects(Note.self)) // Fetch all notes from Realm
}

List {
    ForEach(viewModel.notes) { note in
        HStack {
            Toggle(isOn: Binding(
                get: { note.isCompleted },
                set: { newValue in
                    viewModel.markNoteAsCompleted(id: note.id)
                }
            ), label: {
                Text(note.title)
                    .strikethrough(note.isCompleted)
                    .foregroundStyle(note.isCompleted ? Color("grey") : Color("white"))
                
                
                
            })
            
            .toggleStyle(iOSCheckboxToggleStyle())
            
            
        }
        .padding(10)
        .listRowBackground(Color("backgroundLightSecond"))
        
    }
    .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
      guard let index = indexSet.first else { return }
      viewModel.deleteNote(atIndex: index)
    })
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    
    
}
.listRowSpacing(10)
.clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 15))
//.listStyle(.plain)
// .background(Color("background"))
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)


You need to point out where your app crashes and you need to provide details about the crash/error message.

@HangarRash hi, I'm updated post and add more information

It's pretty perilous to deal with indices because they can change when items are inserted, deleted or the order changes. It's more reliable to get the object always by its id.

Could you also post your view where you showing objects? Also, it would be wonderful to know whether notes os array/list of realm objects or not.

From what I can see you do integration of Realm wrong way. Realm has great API for SwiftUI, which you should have a look at, especially for ObservedResults wrapper. Speaking of your problem - you delete the object from realm, and then you tried to access the same object while deleting it from array, which is not possible, cause it was deleted. You either need to create a separate type(which I encourage you not to do) and make all operation on it, before you do on your realm object or read about  ObservedResults and integrate it into code base.

@Suprafen Excellent comment and probably should be added as an answer. OP: For additional clarity; deleting the object from Realm does not remove that objects' index from the array. The element at that index is now nil, causing the crash. You should not cast Realm collections to arrays if possible - see my answer here for details.

When you called deleteNotes, inside the method you're deleting Realm object:
realm.delete(objectToDelete)

And the next line, you're trying to remove the object you've just deleted from array, which causes crash.
notes.remove(at: index)

Instead of making an Array of Realm objects, you should use @ObservedResults property wrapper. Which helps you to observe a collection of results. But it is intended to be used in SwiftUI Views!
Usage is fairly simple and would look like this:
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedResults(Note.self) private var notes
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(notes) { note in
            // Code for view-cell customization
            }
            .onDelete($notes.remove)
        }
    }
}


As you probably noticed, it allows you to remove your objects just in one line by calling $notes.remove in onDelete() modifier.
You can learn more about @ObservedResults on Realm's documentation
